# jquery dataTable binding issue with angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, datatables-1.10

I have initialized data table, but its not working fine

```
function CompaniesList() {
    $http.get('/Companies/GetList')
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.CompaniesList = result.data;
            $('#myTable').DataTable();
            //if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#myTable')) {
            //    $('#myTable').dataTable();
            //}
        }, function () {
        })
}
```

[image]

Comment: check the image attached with question

Comment: did you load the exact js file?

Comment: yes,  I added the file
on load its shows data table 
when I click sort or search something it breaks

Comment: also tell me how to add server side pagination in this datatable ?

Comment: don't you have any configuration for databale? or are you using static table to produce the datatable?
regarding the server side datatables pagination, The datatables already have certain get parameters that are well specified in the documentation of datatables. "https://datatables.net/manual/server-side" You may use the parameters and generate the logic to produce data accordingly

Comment: Here are the options that are available in the datatables "https://datatables.net/reference/option/"

Comment: i know there is documentation for this but when ajax request complete where data goes from where to display in table

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
this is the basic example given in documentation where is server side in this code, this is also a same request when we fetch data first time and pass to datatable then after how to handle further data ?

Comment: DataTables has an inbuilt `ajax` options. You may use it like `$.ajax`

Comment: how to send parameters ?
max rows, current etc etc

Comment: those parameters will be sent by datatables automatically. All you have to do is to get those parameters in the server side and process it.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at xb (jquery.dataTables.min.js:39)
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:37
    at i (jquery.dataTables.min.js:35)
    at Object.success (jquery.dataTables.min.js:35)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Make sure you serve the data from the server as the format specified in the datatables documentation.

Comment: link please ? i dont have any idea about this

Comment: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

take a look at the sample data

Comment: public class JQueryDataTableParamModel
        {
            public string sEcho { get; set; }
            public string sSearch { get; set; }
            public int iDisplayLength { get; set; }
            public int iDisplayStart { get; set; }
        }
is found this but these parameteres are 0 or null on request

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that i couldn't post such a long code in comment, so I am posting this as an answer

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        url: 'your url', // the url to request for.
        data: function (d) {
            // d is the default dataset of the datatables..
            // append your data items if you have any extra parameters to pass to "d". like d['sample'] = 'new data';
            return d;
        },
        type: 'GET', // default is GET and if you need you may change them to POST.
        dataType: 'json'
    };
});
```

You can get all the parameters of the datatables as get parameters along with the extra parameters that you send.

Comment: and where data returns ? just like normal ajax request ?

Comment: returned data will be automatically handled by datatables. If you want them to be processed as something else, then you may add `success` parameter with a `function` that returns the `processed data`

Comment: Also you may process the data for different columns as you wish by using the `render` property inside `columns` property of datatables.